# auto cleanup maven project dependencies

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I inherited a large codebase built with maven multi modules. 
I want to explicitly reference dependencies used in the source code itself, categorize by compile/test 
and delete dependencies that are not used at test/runtime.

Is there a tool/plugin that does this for me or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The dependency plugin offers `mvn dependency:analyze` which allows you to find out which dependencies are actually used in your source code. It furthermore tells you if you use transitive dependencies directly in your source code.

I do not know whether you can do something like that for test code as well.